# ¿Como puedo saber la ubicación de un sitio web?

Tags: http

mi duda es como saber la ubicación de un sitio web, si esta alojado en Europa o en América por ejemplo?
O hay alguna web donde pueda ver donde están alojadas determinadas paginas? 
Es porque tengo un sensor de PRTG que analiza el ping (en ms) de una web y quería compararlos entre si.
Disculpen no sabia que etiqueta usar y tampoco es sobre código especifico.

Comment: Échale un vistazo al plugin de firefox https://flagfox.wordpress.com/ trae integrado todos los servicios como Whois, Alexa, etc

Comment: ten en cuenta que si el sitio usa un CDN, solo obtendrías la ubicación del CDN y no del origen. saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navegando por google encontre eso, espero te sirva

http://www.dnsqueries.com/es/localizar_lugar_direccion_ip.php

Comment: Gracias estimado.

Comment: Igual podrias incluir algunos detalles aqui, para cuando el sitio que aloja el contenido deje de funcionar, la respuesta siga teniendo sentido

Answer (score 1):

Dale un check con esto: https://www.woorank.com lo que te genera información interesante y de manera gratuita

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la IP :
http://get-site-ip.com/

por ejemplo www.ziarulactualitatea.ro  obtiene la dirección IP 188.213.22.57

teniendo la IP usa :
https://www.iplocation.net/

para obtener datos de geolocalización además de Pais, Region, Ciudad.

o directamente con la ip obtienes mediante google maps la localización mediante:
http://www.ipfingerprints.com/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existe una página que usaba en otro trabajo pero ahora no la recuerdo y considero más completa, posteriormente la agrego a mi respuesta!.